# Comunicação entre PHP e Android

Tags: php, android

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP utilizado este comandos:

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Pois os dados são enviados pelo sistema Android.

O que é enviado para o PHP é um JSON, depois de receber faço um parse e valido as informação do json

Gostaria de saber se esta é a melhor forma de receber os dados, que tipo de segurança posso implementar?

Comment: Sim, para receber os dados em formato *JSON* no seu servidor essa é a forma correta de se fazer. Agora, sobre segurança, o que exatamente você se refere?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues estava lendo sobre isto "allow_url_fopen" e pelo eu vi deixa o sistema aberto para tentativas de invasão.

Comment: Dependendo do dado, você pode passar ele criptografado por um hash, recomendo o `bcrypt();`

Comment: Eu desenvolvo em IOS, e os dados que o meu app passa para o servidor, são criptografados no IOS, passados para servidor, e depois o servidor criptografa eles novamente.